# Xamarin.Forms ListView disable selection on UWP

Tags: listview, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

When using a Xamarin.Forms ListView, is there any way to remove the automatic scrolling of the ListView to a selected cell on UWP while still allowing the selection of elements within the cell layout? Also, is there any way to remove the "selected" animation on the cell in the same situation?

I have managed to achieve the visual effect by disabling hit detection entirely in the ListViewRenderer like so:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
var setter = new Setter(ListViewItem.IsHitTestVisibleProperty, false);
style.Setters.Add(setter);
((ListView)Control).ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

However clearly this also disables hit detection of elements within the cell.

Is there any way in UWP to achieve the disabling of animation/ListView autoscrolling while still allowing detection of buttons etc. within the cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On UWP, `ListView`s have a `SelectionMode` property, that can be set to `None`. This might be the easiest way to disable the auto-scrolling. Unfortunately, this property does not get reflected in the Xamarin.Forms abstraction of the `ListView`.

To set this (only on UWP) you don't really need a Custom Renderer, a [Xamarin.Forms Effect](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/) should do the job. So you could simply create an `NoSelectionEffect` class inside your Xamarin.Forms UWP project and let it look like this:

```
using ListViewScrollingTestForms.UWP;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyCompany")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(NoSelectionEffect), "NoSelectionEffect")]
namespace ListViewScrollingTestForms.UWP
{
    public class NoSelectionEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            // Set selection mode to 'None'     
            (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView).SelectionMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode.None;            
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            // Set selection mode back to the default one of Xamarin.Forms (Single)
            (Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView).SelectionMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you need to create a class for the renderer inside the Xamarin.Forms PCL:

```
public class NoSelectionEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public NoSelectionEffect() : base("MyCompany.NoSelectionEffect") {}
}
```

Now you can attach the Effect to your `ListView`, which should do the job.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Effects>
        <local:NoSelectionEffect />
    </ListView.Effects>
</ListView>
```

Let me know, if this helps!